# How to consume Provider after navigating to another route?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

My app have 2 type of user: admin and normal. I show admin screen to admin and normal screen to normal user. All user need access `Provider` `model1`. But only admin need access `model2`.

How I can initialise only `model2` for admin user?

For example:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final model1 = Model1();

  final model2 = Model2();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return MultiProvider(
    providers: [
ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (_) => model1),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (_) => model2),
    ],
    child: MaterialApp(
```

I want to put `model2` only in `AdminScreen`. But if I do this other admin pages cannot access `model2` after `Navigator.push` because they are not descendant of `AdminScreen`.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 24):

You can pass the existing model forward creating a new `ChangeNotifierProvider` using the value of the existing one.

For that, you need to use `ChangeNotifierProvider.value` constructor passing the existing `model2` as the value.

> If you already have an instance of ChangeNotifier and want to expose it, you should use ChangeNotifierProvider.value instead of the default constructor.

```dart
MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider<Model2>.value(
    value: model2,
    child: SecondRoute(),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! You are correct with `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider` I can access `model1`. But this will only be scope to page where I access it. `model2` will not be available to other Navigation route after `Navigator.push()`. You can give example?

Comment: wrap the pushed child into a `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider` so you can copy the existing model2's state

Comment: Thanks!! I have try but I cannot understand how to do. I still get error cannot find correct provider. Are you mean like this: `Navigator.push(model2)`. You can give code?

Comment: @FlutterFirebase I've changed my answer as ProxyProvider will not fix your problem

Comment: Is there a way to expose th model by using named push method?

Comment: you can pass as a param when declaring the routes, then you can create the `ChangeNotifierProvider` using this param inside the destination widget